# Fitting all of the views onto one table row

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to put a TextView into my TableView so that it doesn't push the spinner box and the other TextView off of the screen.  I've tried changing the layout_width, yet that has not worked.  I have also tried changing the layout_width of the TableRow, but that is not working, either.  So how can I fit the text of the left-most textView in the row?

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/abilityScoreTable"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:padding="0dip">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="30dip" android:id="@+id/abilityScoreBannerText" android:text="Ability Scores"></TextView>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView android:text="zero" android:id="@+id/StrengthBonusText" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/StrengthSpinner" android:layout_width="10px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:entries="@array/string_ability_scores"></Spinner>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/StrengthTextView" android:text="Strength"
android:textSize="30dip"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:gravity="center">
        <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/dexteritySpinner" android:entries="@array/string_ability_scores"></Spinner>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text="Dexterity" android:textSize="30dip"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/string_ability_scores" android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/TableRow3">
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/ConstitutionSpinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/string_ability_scores"></Spinner>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Constitution" android:textSize="30dip"
android:id="@+id/ConstitutionTextView"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:gravity="center">
        <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/intelligenceSpinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/string_ability_scores"></Spinner>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Intelligence" android:textSize="30dip"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
android:gravity="center">
        <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/WisdomSpinner" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/string_ability_scores"></Spinner>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text="Wisdom"
android:textSize="30dip"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
android:gravity="center">
        <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/CharismaSpinner" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/string_ability_scores"></Spinner>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Charisma" android:textSize="30dip"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Layout with TextView off-screen]

On the top-most spinner there's suppose to be a number to the left.  I'm trying to squeeze it on to the screen and have all three fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure what you want any way check this and tell me is this what you are trying.

[image]

if so here is the xml.

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
    <TextView android:text="zero" android:id="@+id/StrengthBonusText"></TextView>
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/StrengthSpinner" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/StrengthTextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Strength" android:textSize="30dip" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
    <View android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="0dip" />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/dexteritySpinner" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Dexterity" android:textSize="30dip" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow3">
    <View android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="0dip" />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/ConstitutionSpinner"></Spinner>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/ConstitutionTextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Constitution" android:textSize="30dip"></TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
    <View android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="0dip"/>
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/intelligenceSpinner"></Spinner>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Intelligence" android:textSize="30dip"></TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
    <View android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="0dip"/>
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/WisdomSpinner"></Spinner>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Wisdom" android:textSize="30dip"></TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow5">
    <View android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="0dip"/>
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/CharismaSpinner"></Spinner>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Charisma" android:textSize="30dip"></TextView>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's about right.  However, I need to fit it on narrower displays.  While the word "zero" fits on your device, I need to move it a bit closer to the spinner box, so that it doesn't push out the word "Strength" on smaller displays.

Comment: did you try this layout? android uses its own scaling down things. between there are things you cannot put a big ball in a small bag. try reducing font size and other stuffs. your question was getting the thing aligned. now for fitting into a small display you have to reduce the lengths of those views by reducing the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a relative layout or is that just not an option? Also I noticed you are mixing px and dip - this is usually not recommended